# The CSS file is unknown in application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The design of the app is not shown to me, even though the CSS file is in the same folder.
I have no idea what my mistake is!

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Burger.css';
import BurgerIngredient from './BurgerIngredient/BurgerIngredient';

const Burger = () => {
    console.log("[Burger.js]");
    return (
        <div className={classes.Burger}>
            <BurgerIngredient type="bread-top" />
            <BurgerIngredient type="cheese" />
            <BurgerIngredient type="meat" />
            <BurgerIngredient type="bread-bottom" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Burger;
```

I appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 'Create React App' or a css/JS bundler like webpack, than you import your stylesheet without the word 'classes'. Also, make sure you have quotes around the className.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Burger.css'; // Tell Webpack that your component uses these styles
import BurgerIngredient from './BurgerIngredient/BurgerIngredient';

const Burger = () => {
    return (
        <div className="Burger">
            <BurgerIngredient type="bread-top" />
            <BurgerIngredient type="cheese" />
            <BurgerIngredient type="meat" />
            <BurgerIngredient type="bread-bottom" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Burger;
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/#buttonjs